# Squarespace banner image not taking full height

Tags: background, squarespace

**The problem**

I have a really tall image that i would like to place in the contact page, this contact page has a centered title, and below it has a contact form, the thing is the image is only occupying the first block with the title.

Let me share you the image and the screenshot.

**Outputs**

This is the image i want to place as background for the whole page.

[Image 1](http://s12.postimg.org/u4d3g40j1/Mitad_Contacto_Full.jpg)

And this is the Failed result.

[Image 2](http://s9.postimg.org/cukeqjlnz/imagen_pregunta.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to provide more info to get an answer to your problem. This looks to be a css / html problem but with the amount of info provided this cannot be determined. Could you provide a link to the page so the markup could be examined?